# Can I copy from one C# console to another?

Tags: c#

I originally used C# Shell Offline Compiler to do my projects, school recently provided all of us with a copy of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. I've copied several console programs and they worked quite well except for the latest which keeps giving me an error in one specific line. What the compiler keep keeps showing is that the line `STOCK.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"ID {x.id} - Name: {x.Name.PadRight(20)} Price: {string.Format("{0:C2}", x.Price)}"));` has some invalid arguments. Please note I've copied the program into the **console** portion of Visual C#

```
    public static class Program 
    {
        public static void Main() 
        {



           Console.WriteLine("                    *****--------------------*****");
           Console.WriteLine("                          Wit Groceries 2020");
           Console.WriteLine("                    *****--------------------*****");
           Console.WriteLine("            Welcome, would you like to do some shopping today?");
           Console.WriteLine("");

           var STOCK = new List<Items>
           {
            new Items{ id = 1, Name = "Bun", Price = 100},
            new Items{ id = 2, Name = "Soda", Price = 80},
            new Items{ id = 3, Name = "Cheese", Price =70},
            new Items{ id = 4, Name = "Tissue", Price = 50},
            new Items{ id = 5, Name = "Fabuloso", Price = 140},
            new Items{ id = 6, Name = "Grace Mackerel", Price = 90},
            new Items{ id = 7, Name = "Rice", Price = 50},
            new Items{ id = 8, Name = "Flour", Price = 40},
            new Items{ id = 9, Name = "Sugar", Price = 30},
           };



           var STOCKDict = STOCK.ToDictionary(i=>i.id);

           var selecteditems = new List<Items>();

           STOCK.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"ID {x.id} - Name: {x.Name.PadRight(20)} Price: {string.Format("{0:C2}", x.Price)}"));
           Console.WriteLine();

           Console.WriteLine(" Enter the number for the item you want, enter 'x' when finihshed");


           do
           {
            var choice = Console.ReadLine();
            if (choice.Trim() =="x")
            {
                break;
            }
            int id;
            if (!int.TryParse(choice, out id))
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Enter number or 'x' ");
               continue;
            }
            if (STOCKDict.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                var item = STOCKDict[id];
                selecteditems.Add(item);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " is added to your list");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(id + " is not available");
            }
           }
           while (true);

           decimal subt = selecteditems.Sum(i=>i.Price);
           decimal GCT = 16.50m;
           decimal GCTamt = (subt*GCT/100);
           decimal total = subt+GCTamt;
           Console.WriteLine("                  Sub-total = " + "$" + subt);
           Console.WriteLine("                  GCT = " + "$" + GCTamt);
           Console.WriteLine("                  You pay " + "$" +total);
           Console.WriteLine();

           while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(                  "Please tender cash");
            decimal tend = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (tend> total)
            {
                decimal change = tend - total;
                Console.WriteLine("You gave " + "$" + tend + " Your change is " + "$" + change);

                break;
            }

            if (tend==total)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(           "No Change, exact amount given");
                break;
            }
            if (tend<total)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(          "Incorrect amount, more cash needed");
            }
        }



        }

    }
    public class Items
    {
        public int id {get; set;}
        public string Name{get; set;}
        public decimal Price {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Just looking at the Syntax highlighting, something is meesed up with the Quotation marks. and that string.Format() call.

Comment: I copied your code into VS Console Project - It runs. Just that you haven't handled null/empty scenarios at Tender change line. Other than that I dont see any errors.

Comment: Yeah but at this point i'm not sure what, it runs perfectly well on C# Shell and a few other online compilers. That line is meant to print the menu that I initialized using the `Items` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't need to perform a string.Format in the middle of an interpolated string because the interpolation is already doing the formatting:

```
STOCK.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"ID {x.id} - Name: {x.Name.PadRight(20)} Price: {string.Format("{0:C2}", x.Price)}"));
```

Would be more simply:

```
STOCK.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"ID {x.id} - Name: {x.Name,-20} Price: {x.Price:C2}"));
```

-

I think however, the problem is that VS2010 is simply too old to understand interpolated string syntax; interp came along in c# 6, which was operable with VS2013+ afaik. Your school haven't really done you any favours giving you a ten year old IDE, especially seeing as VS2019 has a free version you can use

You'll have to remove the interpolated string and use old style format:

```
STOCK.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ID {0} - Name: {1,-20} Price: {2:C2}", x.id, x.Name, x.Price)));
```

Comment: You sir are a lifesaver, guess I'll have to take it up with admin as it relates to VS2019